# mu4e without mu server process

Tags: mu4e, advice

Occasionally I get error from `mu4e` `error in process sentinel: Database is locked by another process`. To solve this issue I usually end up to kill the process in `list-process` or sometimes `pkill emacs` in bash. That had been very frustrating so I thought about killing `*mu4e-prcess*` every time some `mu4e` command ends up executing. In a lisp I do implement it with advice

```
(defun my-mu4e-kill (frm &rest args)
  (mu4e~proc-kill)
)

(advice-add 'mu4e~proc-send-command :after #'my-mu4e-kill)
```

Briefly testing I was able to open multiple `mu4e` instances and look into maildirs and mail. But I came across two issues.

First one is that `mu4e` does not wait for update process to finish before it exits. Second one is that I no longer are able to open `mu4e` starting it with command `emacsclient -c -e "(mu4e)"` from which I get an error:

```
*ERROR*: Lisp nesting exceeds ‘max-lisp-eval-depth’
```

while `emacs --eval "(mu4e)"` works fine!

Why I am getting these errors and is it possible to resolve them in my `.emacs`?

Comment: The running process is a trademark of mu4e and this is exactly the reason why I don't use that library (after having spent a few hours playing with it).  There are alternatives such as Wanderlust that do not use a running process 24/7.  To alter mu4e to not use a running process 24/7 will undoubtedly bring headaches, such as the one you are experiencing.  In my opinion, it is a fundamentally flawed design -- but a lot of people seem to like that library, so each to his own.

Comment: @lawlist I actually chose `mu4e` because it seemed most popular option on the Internet. It is very good when it works. I feel quite optimistic to resolve these issues in a way I have began.

Comment: Yup. Same issues. Very annoying. I want to fetch a different channel and index and I cant.